# Unity Can I use yield return new WaitUntil(() => GameObject.Find("xx")) in IEnumerator Start()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to stop the Code in my Script until it finds a GameObject and then continue.

I tried it in my Start Method with the following Code :

```
yield return new WaitUntil(() => GameObject.Find("Ball1"));
```

GameObject.Instantiate ...

But this doesn't work (Never Instantiates my GameObject)

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong or have another idea?

Comment: Looking for a gameobject every frame is very bad for performances. Which script creates your ball? I would use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to store a reference to the object you are looking for. Then, the script which instantiate the ball would set the value of this property. Then, in your coroutine, just check if the reference to the object is not null.

Comment: Your code is fine. It should wait until *"Ball1"* Object is found in the scene. So if you instantiate an Object from another script and rename it to *"Ball1"*, that wait should then exit. Before you say *"it doesn't work"* please use `Debug.Log` before that line of code and after it to see what is exactly failing. Also look in the Hierarchy tab to make sure that there is an Object actually named *"Ball1"* which is **active**. If the object is not active, `GameObject.Find` can't find it.

Comment: Answer: "Yes, but please don't."

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't use GameObject.Find each frame (that's what WaitUntil does according to the unity docs)
Secondly, about why it isn't working, GameObject.Find returns null if the specifies gameobject isn't found else it returns the reference to the gameobject. Try returning true and false for that and it might work
So

```
WaitUntil(() => GameObject.Find("name") != null)
```